# pandas: Use apply to get columns with two highest values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas dataframe and for each row would like to get the indices to the columns containing the two highest values

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 10], "C": [3,4,5], "D": [4,5,6], "E": [7,6,7]})
df.apply(lambda x: np.argsort(x)[::-1][0:2], raw=True, axis=1)
# eventually i would like to assign them to two columns, but the above already fails...
df['first'], df['second'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: np.argsort(x)[::-1][0:2], raw=True, axis=1))
```

I get the error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 2), indices imply (3, 5)`, how do i prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
N = 2
out = df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argpartition(df.to_numpy(), -N)[:, -N:]]
```

output:

```
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'B'],
       ['B', 'A']], dtype=object)
```

As Series:

```
pd.Series(out.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
0    [A, B]
1    [A, B]
2    [B, A]
dtype: object
```

If you want them in (relative) sorted order, better use [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
N = 2
out = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argsort(df.to_numpy())[:, :-N-1:-1]])
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  B  A
1  B  A
2  A  B
```

Answer (score 1):

With `np.argsort` on `df.values`:

```
df.columns.values[np.argsort(df.values, axis=1)[:, -2:]]
```

---

```
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'B'],
       ['B', 'A']], dtype=object)
```

---

```
%timeit df.columns.values[np.argsort(df.values, axis=1)[:, -2:]]
3.45 µs ± 17.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argpartition(df.to_numpy(), -2)[:, -2:]]
5.11 µs ± 98.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply()` works per column but you want to process the dataframe per row. You can transpose the dataframe before and after `apply()`:

```
df.T.apply(lambda x: np.argsort(x)[::-1][0:2]).T
```

Output:

```
   E  D
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
```

You can join the result with the original dataframe after renaming the two new columns:

```
df.join(
    df.T.apply(
        lambda x: np.argsort(x.values)[::-1][0:2]).T.rename(
            columns={0: "first", 1: "second"}
        )
)
```

Output:

```
    A   B  C  D  E  first  second
0  10  20  3  4  7      1       0
1  20  30  4  5  6      1       0
2  30  10  5  6  7      0       1
```

Note that I use `x.values` in the lambda function to discard the columns; this makes it easier to rename them later.